# has_many...:through association not working despite proper modelling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am writing a keyword search algorithm. The keywords are stored in the `keywords` table/model, and submissions (in which the searching takes place) are stored in the `submissions` table/model.  There is also a `submission_keywords` table that links `submissions` to `keywords` via their unique `ids` in accordance with (what I'm pretty sure is) the `has_many :through` setup.  However, when I try to display the `keywords` for a `submission` in my `Show` view:

```
<p>
  <b>Keywords:</b>
  <% @submission.keywords.each do |kw| %>
  <%= kw.name %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

I get an error:

```
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError
Could not find the association :submission_keyword in model Submission
```

Here is my code for these 3 models:

Submission.rb:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :count, :is_sent, :is_success, :stamp, :url
  has_many :submission_keywords, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :keywords, :through => :submission_keyword
end
```

Keyword.rb:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :priority, :type
  has_many :submission_keywords, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :submissions, :through => :submission_keyword
end
```

Submission_Keyword.rb

```
class SubmissionKeyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :freq, :keyword_id, :submission_id, :weight
  belongs_to :submission
  belongs_to :keyword
end
```

and here is the code that requests the `keywords` for a `submission` in the view:

I've seen a lot of posts where people forgot to include a `has_many` association with the `:through` model, but as you can see I covered that.  Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little mistake. It should have been:

```
has_many :keywords, :through => :submission_keywords
```

and

```
has_many :submissions, :through => :submission_keywords
```

Notice submission_keyword**s**